# otool , nm, dsdump and jtool not able to list mach-o binary's symbols

Tags: symbols, mach-o

I have encountered this twice recently where I am trying to list the external symbols for an iOS mach-o binary and none of the tools can provide any output.  The following is an example of the output from jtool:

```
jtool -S BinaryName -arch arm64
             U 
             U 
             U 
             U 
             U 
             U 
             U 
             U
```

This particular binary was a fat binary hence having to pass it the arch but I also tried thinning it and running the command on just the arm64.  The previous binary I had encountered this was not a fat binary though. Unfortunately I can't actually share either of the binaries, which I appreciate makes it harder to answer, as they are from a client.

I thought I had a reasonable understanding of the mach-o format although very inexperienced reversing.

I don't know if this is a trick I'm not aware of, how are these symbols resolved at runtime if they can't be parsed by any of these tools?  Is there a way to "undo" this and list the symbols normally without running the binary?

Comment: First of all, it's very hard to answer without seeing the binary. Second, it's possible that you didn't thinned the binary correctly, as [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40997366/12941478) suggested that only using xcode working.

Comment: Hi @PiPony. Yes I appreciate it is much more difficult without the binary.  Unfortunately this was a client's app that I wasn't able to share, if I come across another instance that I can do though I will provide more details.  Regarding your second point, I had tried with a number of different tools, on the fat and thinned binary, all of which gave the same results.